# Joining two tables with the condition of 'whereNotIn' returns wrong rows in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

I have two tables:

**TABLE_A** has these columns:

```
id - rule_id - car_id

100 - 3 - 5

101 - 4 - 5

102 - 2 - 6

103 - 3 - 6
```

and **TABLE_B** has more columns but the ones needed here:

```
id - car_id

70 - 5

71 - 6
```

I want to join these two tables. My code is below:

```
$ruleIds = [1,2,3]; // Got from user: User wants to see cars that are not included in those(1,2,3) rules.
$cars = Car::where('type', $type);
$result = $cars->join('rule', 'rule.car_id', 'car.car_id')
    ->whereNotIn('rule.rule_id', $ruleIds);
```

but what mysql does is like below:

Joins two tables on `rule.car_id` and `car.car_id`
Checks where `rule.rule_id != 1`, `rule.rule_id != 2`, `rule.rule_id != 3`.

However for car_id of 6 it returns the record while I have declared `whereNotIn('rule.rule_id', [1,2,3])`. It says to himself car_id of 6 doesn't have rule_id of 2 but the second one with rule_id of 3 is not equal to 2 so again it returns the record.

How can I prevent returning records for each condition in order not to return value if one of the `whereNotIn` conditions matches not necessarily all of them?

for example: If I(as a user) set 1,2 for rules, it shouldn't return car with car_id of 6 from cars table because in rules table we have a rule that its rule_id is 2 (one of rules I(user) set).

So if 1..To return all
if 2..To return car_id of 5
if 3..To return none
if 1,2,3,4..To return none

Regarding to "Edit your question and show sample output based on rules_id = (1, 2). Show this as a table, and not as illegible text." I want the return value to be:

Array ()

[image]

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: The return value is all records from cars table `car_id` column which are matched to rules table `car_id` column. I want to return only values which ARE NOT in rules table rule_id column set by user.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample output based on `rules_id = (1, 2)`.  Show this as a _table_, and _not_ as illegible text.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification. Now you are not clear. Eg vague informal verbs like "checks" & "it says to itself" are not clear; what is clear is, it returns the rows where rule.rule_id != 1 and rule.rule_id != 2 and rule.rule_id != 3. You give a tangle of unclear sentences about what you don't want the erroneous query to do etc. Please use enough technical terms & phrases & sentences to be clear. Please give a clear straightforward statement of what rows you want in the output based on what rows are in the input.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. This will be a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the problem with the help of @TimBiegeleisen answer:

```
$paramValues = explode(',', $data['rules']);
$paramKeys = '';
for($p=1; $p<=$paramCount; $p++)
{
    $paramKeys .= '?,';
}
$paramKeys = rtrim($paramKeys, ',');

$cars->join('rule', 'rule.car_id', 'cars.car_id')
    ->whereRaw("cars.car_id NOT IN (SELECT car_id FROM rule WHERE rule_id IN (".$paramKeys."))", $paramValues)
    ->groupBy('cars.car_id');
```

1. I'm sorry for bad English or bad explanation :)
2. For preventing sql injection I did that for loop. Is there any other better approach for this?
3. In the query there is another select but I wanted to do this only with join and simple. Is there any other approach to get this?

Thanks All :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what your raw MySQL query might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b
    ON a.car_id = b.car_id
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A a2
                 WHERE a.car_id = a2.car_id AND a2.rule_id IN (1, 2));
```

Laravel code:

```
$cars = Car::where('type', $type);
$result = $cars->join('rule', 'rule.car_id', 'car.car_id')
    ->where(DB::raw("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rule r2
                 WHERE rule.car_id = r2.car_id AND r2.rule_id IN (1, 2))"));
```

Note that I did not make an attempt to make the `rule_id` values you want to screen dynamic.  That is, I do not bind your `$ruleIds` array to the query.  The reason for this is that it is difficult to do this for an unknown number of rules.  But, the above code should put you on the right track.

Comment: When I set 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 3 or any other number for the rules it returns all the cars however I want no cars to return. Because 2,3,4 are the rules that each car has, so they shouldn't be included in the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = App\Car::whereHas('rules', function ($query)use($ruleIds) {
    $query->whereNotIn('rule_id',  $ruleIds);
})->get();
```